# Change html button content on success

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I just want to toggle html button content(activate or deactivate) on click of button...now if button content is activate it changes this to deactivate....but not vice-versa... please have look on ajax code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"  onclick="savestatus<?php echo $row->id; ?>(<?php echo $row->id; ?>)">Activate</button>
```

and my script is

```
  <script>
 function savestatus<?php echo $row->id; ?>(row_id){
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/activate_buyer/'. $row->id; ?>",
    data:{},       
    success:function( data )
    {
       $("#"+row_id).html("Deactivate");
    }
   });
}

</script>
```

please help...

Comment: any error in console ?? @Pardeep

Comment: How are you interacting with database as you are using AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**text**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to change the text of the button

```
  $("#"+row_id).text("Deactivate");
```

**EDIT**

> i want if text is activate then onclick it becomes deactivate and
>   vice-versa

```
$('.button').click(function(event){
$(this).text().trim()==="Active"?$(this).text("Deactive"):$(this).text("Active")
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/1247/)

Comment: didnt work...i want if text is activate then onclick it becomes deactivate and vice-versa.. but now it is only showing deactivate on click

Comment: @Pardeep check this demo

Comment: I think your source is good but not OP wishes. He need change to Deactive when Ajax success and don't want click again for get `Active` button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bro

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $row= 5;
?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="<?php echo $row; ?>"  onclick="savestatus(this)">Activate</button>  
<script>
function savestatus(ele) {
    var id = ele.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php 'http://localhost/testGuzzle/jsOnChange2.php'; ?>",
        data:{
            test: id,
        },       
        success:function( data )
        {
           $("#"+id).html("Deactivate");
        }
       });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change your `url` at script.

My result

[image]